# Bootstrap 2 columns but not another row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my Markup for the bootstrap

```html
<script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"/>
<pre>
  <div class="row">
  <div
    class="col-lg-6 boxListCont">
  
    <h3 class="fs-32 mb-30">California</h3>
    
    <a
      href="http://www.realitysb.com/carpinteria/"
      class="full lh-80 mb-25 boxList color-white1"
      data-aos="fade-up"
      data-aos-offset="10"
      data-aos-delay="1"
      data-aos-duration="700">
    <span class="boxDCont">
      <span
        class="boxD fs-32 color-black1 uppercase bg-yellow">CPN</span>
      </span>
      <span class="pl txtD pl-25">
      <em class="ellipsis">Carpinteria</em>
      <i class="svg-ico"
         data-svg="angleArr"></i>
    </span>
    </a>
    
    <a href="http://realitysf.com/"
       class="full lh-80 mb-25 boxList color-white1"
       data-aos="fade-up"
       data-aos-offset="10"
       data-aos-delay="1"
       data-aos-duration="700">
    <span class="boxDCont">
    <span
      class="boxD fs-32 color-black1 uppercase bg-yellow">SF</span>
    </span>
    <span class="pl txtD pl-25">
    <em class="ellipsis">San Francisco</em>
    <i class="svg-ico"
       data-svg="angleArr"></i>
    </span>
    </a>
    
    <a href="http://www.realitysb.com/"
       class="full lh-80 mb-25 boxList color-white1"
       data-aos="fade-up"
       data-aos-offset="10"
       data-aos-delay="1"
       data-aos-duration="700">
    <span class="boxDCont">
    <span
      class="boxD fs-32 color-black1 uppercase bg-yellow">SB</span>
    </span>
    <span class="pl txtD pl-25">
    <em class="ellipsis">Santa Barbara</em>
    <i class="svg-ico"
       data-svg="angleArr"></i>
    </span>
    </a>
    
    <a
      href="http://www.realitystockton.com/"
      class="full lh-80 mb-25 boxList color-white1"
      data-aos="fade-up"
      data-aos-offset="10"
      data-aos-delay="1"
      data-aos-duration="700">
    <span class="boxDCont">
    <span
      class="boxD fs-32 color-black1 uppercase bg-yellow">STK</span>
    </span>
    <span class="pl txtD pl-25">
    <em class="ellipsis">Stockton</em>
    <i class="svg-ico"
       data-svg="angleArr"></i>
    </span>
    </a>
    
    <a
      href="http://www.realitysb.com/ventura/"
      class="full lh-80 mb-25 boxList color-white1"
      data-aos="fade-up"
      data-aos-offset="10"
      data-aos-delay="1"
      data-aos-duration="700">
    <span class="boxDCont">
    <span
      class="boxD fs-32 color-black1 uppercase bg-yellow">VEN</span>
    </span>
    <span class="pl txtD pl-25">
    <em class="ellipsis">Ventura</em>
    <i class="svg-ico"
       data-svg="angleArr"></i>
    </span>
    </a>
    </div>
    <div
      class="col-lg-6 boxListCont">
    
    <h3
      class="fs-32 mb-30">Massachusetts</h3>
    
    <a
      href="http://www.realityboston.com/"
      class="full lh-80 mb-25 boxList color-white1"
      data-aos="fade-up"
      data-aos-offset="10"
      data-aos-delay="1"
      data-aos-duration="700">
    <span class="boxDCont">
    <span
      class="boxD fs-32 color-black1 uppercase bg-yellow">BST</span>
    </span>
    <span class="pl txtD pl-25">
    <em class="ellipsis">Boston</em>
    <i class="svg-ico"
       data-svg="angleArr"></i>
    </span>
    </a>
    </div>
    <div
      class="col-lg-6 boxListCont">
    
    <h3 class="fs-32 mb-30">Hawaii</h3>
    
    <a
      href="http://realityhonolulu.com/"
      class="full lh-80 mb-25 boxList color-white1"
      data-aos="fade-up"
      data-aos-offset="10"
      data-aos-delay="1"
      data-aos-duration="700">
    <span class="boxDCont">
    <span
      class="boxD fs-32 color-black1 uppercase bg-yellow">HNL</span>
    </span>
    <span class="pl txtD pl-25">
    <em class="ellipsis">Honolulu</em>
    <i class="svg-ico"
       data-svg="angleArr"></i>
    </span>
    </a>
    </div>
    
    
  </div>
</pre>
```

They are in two columns but there is space at the right left, I want to push the Hawaii state at  the right as well so that space is fill at the right, I am making it for wordpress with php. I can change the structure for it but I want to do it with bootstrap,

here is the screenshot of the preview[image]

Comment: as long as bootstrap grid divided to 12 cols so you have to work on that =)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-lg-6 boxListCont text-center">
```

Try adding 'text-center' to the columns you want to push more to the right

Comment: actually I want Huwaii [HNL] at the bottom of [BST]

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap grid system lets you to control your view within each row, so you have 12 column in each row, to achieve your goal you need to divide it on your view, as long as you need to show the 3 parents at the top, so you can go for `col-lg-4` for each column of the 3 cols, so you will have them all together at the top

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<pre>
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6 boxListCont">                                                           <h3 class="fs-32 mb-30">California</h3>
<a href="http://www.realitysb.com/carpinteria/" class="full lh-80 mb-25 boxList color-white1" data-aos="fade-up"
data-aos-offset="10" data-aos-delay="1" data-aos-duration="700">
<span class="boxDCont">
<span class="boxD fs-32 color-black1 uppercase bg-yellow">CPN</span></span><span class="pl txtD pl-25"><em class="ellipsis">Carpinteria</em><i class="svg-ico" data-svg="angleArr"></i></span></a><a href="http://realitysf.com/" class="full lh-80 mb-25 boxList color-white1" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-offset="10" data-aos-delay="1" data-aos-duration="700">
<span class="boxDCont">
<span class="boxD fs-32 color-black1 uppercase bg-yellow">SF</span>
</span>
<span class="pl txtD pl-25">
<em class="ellipsis">San Francisco</em>
<i class="svg-ico" data-svg="angleArr"></i>
</span>
</a>
<a href="http://www.realitysb.com/" class="full lh-80 mb-25 boxList color-white1" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-offset="10" data-aos-delay="1" data-aos-duration="700">
<span class="boxDCont">
<span class="boxD fs-32 color-black1 uppercase bg-yellow">SB</span>
                                </span>
                                            <span class="pl txtD pl-25">
                                    <em class="ellipsis">Santa Barbara</em>
                                    <i class="svg-ico" data-svg="angleArr"></i>
                                </span>
                                        </a>
                                    
                                        <a href="http://www.realitystockton.com/"
                                           class="full lh-80 mb-25 boxList color-white1" data-aos="fade-up"
                                           data-aos-offset="10"
                                           data-aos-delay="1" data-aos-duration="700">
                                <span class="boxDCont">
                                    <span class="boxD fs-32 color-black1 uppercase bg-yellow">STK</span>
                                </span>
                                            <span class="pl txtD pl-25">
                                    <em class="ellipsis">Stockton</em>
                                    <i class="svg-ico" data-svg="angleArr"></i>
                                </span>
                                        </a>
                                    
                                        <a href="http://www.realitysb.com/ventura/"
                                           class="full lh-80 mb-25 boxList color-white1" data-aos="fade-up"
                                           data-aos-offset="10"
                                           data-aos-delay="1" data-aos-duration="700">
                                <span class="boxDCont">
                                    <span class="boxD fs-32 color-black1 uppercase bg-yellow">VEN</span>
                                </span>
                                            <span class="pl txtD pl-25">
                                    <em class="ellipsis">Ventura</em>
                                    <i class="svg-ico" data-svg="angleArr"></i>
                                </span>
                                        </a>
                                                                    </div>
                                                            <div class="col-lg-6 boxListCont">
<div class="row">                                                            <div class="col-lg-12 boxListCont">

                                    <h3 class="fs-32 mb-30">Massachusetts</h3>
                                    
                                        <a href="http://www.realityboston.com/"
                                           class="full lh-80 mb-25 boxList color-white1" data-aos="fade-up"
                                           data-aos-offset="10"
                                           data-aos-delay="1" data-aos-duration="700">
                                <span class="boxDCont">
                                    <span class="boxD fs-32 color-black1 uppercase bg-yellow">BST</span>
                                </span>
                                            <span class="pl txtD pl-25">
                                    <em class="ellipsis">Boston</em>
                                    <i class="svg-ico" data-svg="angleArr"></i>
                                </span>
                                        </a>
                                                                    </div>
                                                            <div class="col-lg-12 boxListCont">

                                    <h3 class="fs-32 mb-30">Hawaii</h3>
                                    
                                        <a href="http://realityhonolulu.com/"
                                           class="full lh-80 mb-25 boxList color-white1" data-aos="fade-up"
                                           data-aos-offset="10"
                                           data-aos-delay="1" data-aos-duration="700">
                                <span class="boxDCont">
                                    <span class="boxD fs-32 color-black1 uppercase bg-yellow">HNL</span>
                                </span>
                                            <span class="pl txtD pl-25">
                                    <em class="ellipsis">Honolulu</em>
                                    <i class="svg-ico" data-svg="angleArr"></i>
                                </span>
                                        </a>
                                                                    </div>
                            

                        </div></div></div>
</pre>
```

Comment: but that will make three columns I want to split the content of single div into two columns

Comment: you can use row inside the 2nd col and use col 12 for each col inside the new row to achieve it

Comment: @SherMuhammad i've edited the snippet try it in full screen =)